# How do I use ServiceStack.Redis message queue to send email notifications?

Tags: redis, message-queue, servicestack

I am digging into the messaging capabilities of the ServiceStack.Redis client and trying to make sense of things. My initial usage would be to queue up notification messages and then process those messages in a windows service that sends the emails out.

1. Can I have multiple instances (on different machines) of RedisMqServer running to process the messages? (From what I am seeing, it looks like that would be fine)
2. If the redis server dies, when it starts back up will the RedisMqServer pickup where it left off and continue processing messages that were in the queue? (I realize that its possible to lose some messages if the redis process dies before they are saved to disk)
3. Do you have any other tips to get started?

Comment: I just did a bunch more research and it seems that redis by default will save to disk every 5 minutes or so depending on your settings. So that seems to be an issue if you don't want to lose messages.  I can change those settings, but I'm not sure how much that will effect using redis as a cache.  Does anyone have any experience with this?  Any recommended persistence settings?  Is there some way to force Redis to save when messages are published?

Answer (score 3):

I found out that by default Redis only saves data around every 5 minutes. I made these changes to my redis.conf file to ensure that I will lose at most 1 second of data in worst case scenarios:

tells redis to use a transaction log and flush it to 
disk every 1 second.
appendonly yes
appendfsync everysec

I tested running multiple processes of RedisMqServer and it works fine.